# Convert multi-dim list in one column in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I would like to know whether I can get some help in "translating" a multi dim list in a single column of a frame in pandas.

I found help here to translate a multi dim list in a column with multiple columns, but I need to translate the data in one

Suppose I have the following list of list

```
x=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

If I create a frame I get

```
frame=pd.Dataframe(x)

0  1  2
1  2  3
4  5  6
```

But my desire outcome shall be

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

with the zero as column header.

I can of course get the result with a for loop, which from my point of view takes much time. Is there any pythonic/pandas way to get it?

Thanks for helping men

Answer (score 5):

You can use `np.concatenate`

```
x=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

frame=pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(x))
print(frame)
```

Output:

```
    0
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
5   6
```

Answer (score 4):

First is necessary [flatten values of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists) and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([z for y in x for z in y])
```

Or:

```
from  itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame(list(chain.from_iterable(x)))
```

---

```
print (df)
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
5  6
```

Comment: wow thank you very much :)
Too stupid to check for flattening or numpy order. thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `numpy` you can utilize the method `ravel()`:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.array(x).ravel())
```